# What is the most efficient way to send an object over a Socket stream?

Tags: java, serialization, stream

I have made an application that uses an ObjectStream to send data to and from a server. When I was connecting to localhost, all worked wonderfully. However, when I created an actual server, the process takes almost 500ms to complete.

I would assume that my objects are too large. I am sending only one Paintables object, which as you can see contains an ArrayList of Paintable's.

```
public class Paintables
        implements Serializable {

    private ArrayList<Paintable> paintables;

    public Paintables() {
        this.paintables = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public Paintables(ArrayList<Paintable> paintables) {
        this.paintables = paintables;
    }

    public final void addPaintable(Paintable paintable) {
        this.paintables.add(paintable);
    }

    public final ArrayList<Paintable> getPaintables() {
        return paintables;
    }
}
```

And then the Paintable class

```
public class Paintable
        implements Serializable {

    private String name;
    private String id;
    private int xLocation;
    private int yLocation;
    private double xRatio;
    private double yRatio;
    private Direction direction;

    public Paintable(String name, String id, int xLocation, int yLocation,
            double xRatio, double yRatio, Direction direction) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.xLocation = xLocation;
        this.yLocation = yLocation;
        this.xRatio = xRatio;
        this.yRatio = yRatio;
        this.direction = direction;
    }

    public final String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public final String getID() {
        return id;
    }

    public final int getXLocation() {
        return xLocation;
    }

    public final int getYLocation() {
        return yLocation;
    }

    public final double getXRatio() {
        return xRatio;
    }

    public final double getYRatio() {
        return yRatio;
    }

    public final Direction getDirection() {
        return direction;
    }
}
```

There are only 2 Paintables contained inside that Arraylist. I cannot fathom why the object is so large that it takes almost a half of a second to be sent over the server.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening? Are Arraylists by nature large objects, and I should be using an Array instead? I know it isn't the Serialization that is taking a long time, because when sending the Paintables over localhost, they were sent and then loaded in <1ms.

If there is any other information you need to determine the issue, please let me know. Thank you.

EDIT:

Direction is the following enum, if that matters at all.

```
public enum Direction {
    STILL, UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT;
}
```

EDIT 2:

I ran a ping app to test the ping to the server, and it returned <1ms, which makes sense because my computer is hosting the server.

EDIT 3:

I also have code that determines how long it takes for the server to send the Paintables, and it takes 2ms. I also have code that determines how long it takes to read the Command from the client (very small Object), and that takes exactly 200ms. It then takes the client exactly 400ms to read the Paintables from the server.

EDIT 4:

Solved by calling "socket.setTcpNoDelay(true)" on both the client socket and the socket created in the server thread. Works like a charm at 60 fps!

Comment: I very much doubt the size of the objects is the problem. It's easy to know: just serialize to a ByteArrayOutputStream, get the byte array from the stream, and get the length of the byte array. I will probably be quite short.

Comment: Maybe a virus scanner is running?

Comment: This is one of the rare cases where you might benefit from disabling the Nagle algorithm (`Socket.setTcpNoDelay(true)`).

Comment: Ah, EJP, thank you! Excellent, that solved everything! Just out of curiosity, what does disabling the Nagle algorithm do? I'm not a fan of just writing code without knowing what it does. Thank you again!

Comment: Long story short, Nagle's algorithm works by buffering small packets of data and sending them all at once in order to reduce overhead. That delay you were experiencing could very well be Nagle's algorithm buffering data prior to be sent. Good catch, btw.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much. Yes, that was definitely the problem.

So as a little side question, I read that Nagle's algorithm should be used only for small pieces of information. Once a map gets larger, and there is more data to be sent, it won't be so small anymore. Would it still be appropriate to have Nagle's algorithm disabled?

Comment: Nagle's isn't necessarily used only for small pieces of information. You see, a TCP/IP packet header has 40 bytes, so sending like 1 byte of actual data equals 4000% overhead, which is bad. So the issue is not the size of the map, but how often your data is being flushed. If you can buffer the data on the client side before flushing, Nagle's can be activated. It depends on your requirements.

Comment: Okay, thank you. That makes sense. Once a map gets larger, I think that it the algorithm will become necessary. Unless I am mistaken, without it, that means that theoretically 4000 time the amount of necessary packets could be sent, which obviously isn't ideal.

I think I have milked this question enough. If I have any additional questions, I should probably make a new thread. Thank you, and I hope this can be useful to someone in the future.

Answer (score 3):

The `Paintable` objects are too small to cause any additional latency. This is probably just caused by the network latency between your computer and the server you are using.

Comment: Just updated my initial post to include that when I ping the server (which is hosted from the same computer the client is running on), I get <1ms ping. I would think that means that the speed of the transfer should be almost instant.

Answer (score 0):

Java's built-in serialization is rather slow. I normally use `gzip`ed json using the Gson-library (https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

You could also go for Google's protocol-buffers: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/

Comment: If the problem was caused by the slowness of the Java serialization, it would also be slow on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

I think what makes your program slow is the serialization process not the network. The ArrayList is not a big object in this case. If you're programming an android application, you can implements Parcelable interface instead. It's faster.